# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 400: "Unexpected response code 400 for https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions" (migrating GPT-3 to GPT-3.5 API)

Tags: android, kotlin, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm getting the following error:

> [3067] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code
> 400 for https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions

The code:

```
private fun getResponseTurbo(query: String) {
    // setting text on for question on below line.
    questionTV.text = query
    queryEdt.setText("")
    // creating a queue for request queue.
    val queue: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
    // creating a json object on below line.
    val jsonObject: JSONObject ? = JSONObject()
    // adding params to json object.

    jsonObject ? .put("model", "gpt-3.5-turbo")
    jsonObject ? .put("messages", "[{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What are your functionalities?'}]")

    jsonObject ? .put("temperature", 0)
    jsonObject ? .put("max_tokens", 48)
    jsonObject ? .put("top_p", 1)
    jsonObject ? .put("frequency_penalty", 0)
    jsonObject ? .put("presence_penalty", 0)

    // on below line making json object request.
    val postRequest: JsonObjectRequest =
        // on below line making json object request.
        object: JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, url_turbo, jsonObject,
            Response.Listener {
                response - >
                    // on below line getting response message and setting it to text view.
                    val responseMsg: String =
                    response.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getString("message")
                chattypingLT.visibility = View.GONE
                ll_copy_share.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                responseTV.text = responseMsg
            },
            // adding on error listener
            Response.ErrorListener {
                error - >
                    Log.e("TAGAPI", "Error is : " + error.message + "\n" + error)
            }) {
            override fun getHeaders(): kotlin.collections.MutableMap < kotlin.String, kotlin.String > {
                val params: MutableMap < String,
                String > = HashMap()
                // adding headers on below line.
                params["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
                params["Authorization"] =
                "Bearer APIKEY"
                return params;
            }
        }

    // on below line adding retry policy for our request.
    postRequest.setRetryPolicy(object: RetryPolicy {
        override fun getCurrentTimeout(): Int {
            return 50000
        }

        override fun getCurrentRetryCount(): Int {
            return 50000
        }

        @Throws(VolleyError::class)
        override fun retry(error: VolleyError) {}
    })
    // on below line adding our request to queue.
    queue.add(postRequest)
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with this API yet `400` means `Bad Request`. This means you have one or more params missing, in wrong format or maybe misspelled. hope this gives you a hint

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model.

There are three main differences between the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API) and the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3 API):

1. API endpoint

   - Completions API: `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions`
   - Chat Completions API: `https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions`
2. The `prompt` parameter (Completions API) is replaced by the `messages` parameter (Chat Completions API)
3. Response access

   - Completions API: 
     `response.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getString("text")`
   - Chat Completions API: `response.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getString("message")`

**PROBLEM**

You got the first and the third bullet point right. This (i.e., the second bullet point) is the problematic part of your code:

```
jsonObject ? .put("messages", "[{'role': 'user', 'content': 'What are your functionalities?'}]")
```

Why?

The JSON for the `messages` parameter in the code you gave is not valid, and that's because it's using single quotes for the string values. In JSON, string values should always be enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes.

**SOLUTION**

Try this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray messages = new JSONArray();
JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

message.put("role", "user");
message.put("content", "What are your functionalities?");

messages.put(message);

jsonObject.put("messages", messages);
```

This code will create the following JSON object:

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "What are your functionalities?"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you're still getting API error `400`, make sure you have set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. Be careful, `application/json, UTF-8` won't work.